# Needed assistance with a java recursive method, described below

Tags: java, recursion

I have an object that has operands and predicates inside.
I have the following model:

```
operand[0] - predicates = NULL
           - operands[0] - predicates = NULL
                         - operands[0] - operands = NULL
                                       - predicates[0] - tableVal="val1.aaa"
                                       - predicates[1] - tableVal="val.bbb"
                                       - predicates[2] = tableVal="val5.ccc"
           - operands[1] - operands = NULL
                         - predicates[0] - tableVal="val3.asd"
                         - predicates[1] - tableVal="val2.ccc"
```

I'm looking for a certain value, that contains "bbb" and I need a recursive method to get through the whole structure until it finds the predicate with the tableVal containing "bbb".

I tried something like this:

```
private String searchInsideStructure(Object obj, int indexOperands) {
    if (null != obj.predicates) {
        indexPredicates = 0;
        while(obj.predicates.length > indexPredicates) {
            if(predicates[indexPredicates].tableVal.contains("bbb")) {
                return tableVal;
            }
            indexPredicates++;
        }
    }
    if (null != obj.operands) {
        while (indexOperands < obj.operands.length) {
            searchInsideStructure(obj.operands[indexOperands], indexOperands);
            indexOperands++;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

.................
indexOperands = 0;
searchedField = searchInsideStructure(initialObj, indexOperands);
if (null != searchedField) {
    return searchedField
}
```

But it returns null. How can I change this recursive method to go through the operands, while finding predicates and finds in predicates the desired tableVal ("val.bbb" in this example)??? Thanks!

Comment: First, in your second loop, you should check the result of the function, and propagate it if non-null. Secondly, you should not need to propagate `indexOperands`, i.e a for (or for each) loop should do the trick instead of a while.

Comment: @amanin, thank you so much, if you post it like an answer I will mark it as the proper answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 fixes to consider:

1. In the second `while` loop, you should verify the result of `searchInsideStructure`, and propagate it if not null
2. You should avoid propagating `indexOperands` because it will make you skip some predicates when testing. You can then just use a for(each) loop to browse predicates.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working now, after I changed it the way you told me.